# How to make a column values unique based on values in other column(s) in R?

Tags: r

I have a large data set similar to as shown in the example below.

```
df <- structure(list(FCN = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("010.X91116.3D3.A8", "010.X91116.6B7.F9", "010.X91116.6C6.C12"
), class = "factor"), DOM = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("VH", "VK"), class = "factor"), FN = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "OM", class = "factor"), 
    RV = c(49257.4, 23571.2, 24115.6, 49351.4, 24102.6, 49641.8, 
    23226.2, 23408.2)), .Names = c("FCN", "DOM", "FN", "RV"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

I am trying to create a table by making FN column values unique with a suffix based on the values in FCN, RV and DOM. I am able to use a for loop and process the data as shown in the figure. However, it takes time when processing thousands of rows.

At the end I want to pivot the data making the values in FN as columns and values in RV. Please guide me how to achieve the results elegantly using some library function if possible.

```
library(reshape2)
pivot_df <- dcast(df, FCN + DOM ~ FN)
```

Comment: The issue I am facing is on how to add a serialized suffix to the FN column? At the end I want to pivot the data making the values in FN as columns and values in RV as the data using reshape2 library function, dcast(df, FCN + DOM ~ FN).

Comment: I posted a solution with updates using `dcast`.  Please check

Comment: okay, no problem, but `dcast` from `data.table` is optimized for efficiency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adopting @akrun's advice:

```
library(reshape2)
df <- structure(list(FCN = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L,  3L), .Label = c("010.X91116.3D3.A8", "010.X91116.6B7.F9", "010.X91116.6C6.C12"), class = "factor"), DOM = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("VH", "VK"), class = "factor"), FN = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "OM", class = "factor"), RV = c(49257.4, 23571.2, 24115.6, 49351.4, 24102.6, 49641.8, 23226.2, 23408.2)), .Names = c("FCN", "DOM", "FN", "RV"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
df$FN <- with(df, paste0(FN, ave(seq_along(FN), FCN, DOM, FUN = seq_along)))
pivot_df <- dcast(df, FCN + DOM ~ FN)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `ave` to do this

```
df$FN <- with(df, paste0(FN, ave(seq_along(FN), FCN, DOM, FUN = seq_along)))
```

If we need to reshape to 'wide', then `rowid` from `data.table` can be used with `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), FCN + DOM ~FN + rowid(DOM), value.var = "RV")
```

Comment: I tweaked the order of the columns and adopted your advice on serializing the FN column values and achieved what I wanted. Thanks a lot.